# @LoadBalanced WebClient doesnt work with @RestClientTest unit tests

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix

I have a few tests annotated as @RestClientTest that uses a @LoadBalanced WebClient.Builder to call a service. I have a MockWebServer running to mock the service on the correct port. I use Ribbon for load balancing. I get the following exception when the tests run:

```
eactor.core.Exceptions$ReactiveException: java.net.UnknownHostException: orchestration

at reactor.core.Exceptions.propagate(Exceptions.java:326)
at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:91)
at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1494) ...
```

My Bean definition:

```
@LoadBalanced
public WebClient.Builder asyncWebClientBuilder() {
    TcpClient tcpClient = TcpClient.create()
            .option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, connectTimeout) // Connection Timeout
            .doOnConnected(connection ->
                    connection.addHandlerLast(new ReadTimeoutHandler(readTimeout))); // Read Timeout)
    return WebClient.builder()
            .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(HttpClient.from(tcpClient)));
```

The Client Code:

```
return client.build()
            .method(method)
            .uri(initUriTemplateHandler()
                    .expand(url, uriVariables))
            .body(BodyInserters.fromObject(requestEntity))
            .exchange()
            .block();
```

Strange thing is, the same exact client code works perfectly when I run it in the real world situation against the real service. I also have a few tests that are `@SpringBootTest` annotated and use the same exact client underneath which loadbalanced and works perfectly. Its not load balanced only for the case of `@RestClientTest` case.
What I am missing here?
I am using Spring Boot 2.1.3

Comment: `@RestClientTest` excludes everything but what is needed by boot to test a rest client. Everything else is excluded. Boot doesn't know about `@LoadBalanced`.

Comment: @spencergibb I am not sure about that. If I replace WebClient with good old RestTemplate, this same test just works fine with Load Balancer.

Comment: @WebTestClient maybe?